# Post request from angular js to django view gives 500 internal server error

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I am sending a post request to a django view from angular js but it gives me 500 (internal server error).

This is my angular file :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.config(function($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider){
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
});
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http){
var details = {
length : $scope.length,
breadth : $scope.breadth,
height : $scope.height,
weight : $scope.weight,
country : $scope.country,
itemType : $scope.itemType
}
var theJSON = JSON.stringify(details);
$http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : '/interApp/calc/',
      data    : $.param(theJSON),
      headers : {'Content-Type': 'data:application/json;charset=utf-8;'+ encodeURIComponent(theJSON) },

     }).success(function(data) {
        console.log(theJSON);
     })

  }
}])
```

and this is the django view :

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from .models import Countries,CourierCompany,Zones,Weight
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def rate_calculator(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ////code goes here...
```

and my urls.py file is :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import CostView
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^calc/', views1.rate_calculator, name='rate_calculator'),
]
```

but it gives me the error in the console window :

POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/interApp/calc/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Comment: I think `data: theJSON,` is enough there

Comment: Try to post data using postman and see there is also same error

Comment: Let if fail - set the `DEBUG = True` in settings and observe the error. Or, if you have logging set up - just explore what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the data in your django function by json, try the same using POSTMAN

```
def rate_calculator(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
      loadedJsonData = json.loads(request.body)
      length = loadedJsonData.get('length')
```

Comment: I have Debug = True and I get the 500 error in the console window of my browser and reading the data doesn't help.

Comment: use that data to hit the same request through postman and then see what exactly the error is. there could be error in your code after reading the post the data.

Answer (score 0):

Your Error is not Clear and I think your URL also seems wrong .. So if Your angular post is  really hit the views? to check print your request under your views. like this,

```
def rate_calculator(request):
    print 'request',request
```

check the content in POST: ......  and try this traceback also.. by simply import ,

```
from traceback import format_exc
```

and put this print statement under your views,

```
 print 'Error report', repr(format_exc())
```

Before that , try this angular POST method,

```
$http.post('/your url/', {
    data: details,
}).success(function(response) {
    console.log('your console')
})
```

Then let me know what is exact error , i think may if you follow this POST, request you wont get Error..
if you got data in your post request get it by using this,

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
```

Comment: doesn't help either.